# How do I find userdir directives

Tags: apache2, webserver

Where do I find the userdir directives from apache2? They aren't in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`.

Comment: have you tried the solution which I posted ?

Answer (score 2):

You take help from [apache on-line documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html).

here is actual steps to enable userdir directives :

**Configuration**

Step1 # enable userdir module

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Step2 # Setting the default file path with UserDir

```
sudo echo 'UserDir public_html'  >> /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdir.conf
```

Step 3 # reload/restart apache to for effect changes made. apache will read `userdir.conf` because apache.conf already have entry of `Include conf.d/`

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

**Testing**

Now apache will read html files from publi_html directory in users home directory. so let create that and test.

Note: assuming that you are log-in using test user

```
mkdir public_html
```

then create test html page

```
echo 'Test Page' >> public_html/index.html
```

Test

```
curl http://localhost/~test/
```

Comment: Yes this should be flagged as an answer, cheers.